# remove selected value from select box using jquery but It's need to display current selected value in select box?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a `select` box and add more `button`. when I click add more `button` it's creating another `select` using clone.In first select box I `select` one `option` value from `select` box means that value should be removed from next created `select` box.At the same time which selected value in select box that current `value` shown on current `select` box. Select box value is being loaded dynamically.

Eg:

```
<select name="section" id="section_1" class="sectionType">
    <option value=" ">------</option>
    <option value="05">test1</option>
    <option value="06">test2</option>
    <option value="07">test3</option>
    <option value="08">test4</option>
    <option value="10">test5</option>
    <option value="11">test6</option>
    <option value="12">test7</option>
    <option value="13">test8</option>
    <option value="14">test9</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it what you're looking for ?

I would recommend you to play and manipulate with `index()`, that won't bother your dynamic values.

```
//Take a clone of last 
var cloneElement = $('.sectionType:last').clone();
//Get index of option selected from last 
var indexToRemove = $('.sectionType:last').find('option:selected').index();
//Remove previously selected index
cloneElement.find('option').eq(indexToRemove).remove();
//Change the id of an element
cloneElement.attr("id", "section_"+parseInt($('.sectionType').length+1));
//If element has options
if(cloneElement.find('option').length)
{
  //Finally append it
  $('body').append("<br/><br/>").append(cloneElement);
}
```

```js
$('button').click(function(){
 
  //Take a clone of last 
  var cloneElement = $('.sectionType:last').clone();
  //Get index of option selected from last 
  var indexToRemove = $('.sectionType:last').find('option:selected').index();
  //Remove previously selected index
  cloneElement.find('option').eq(indexToRemove).remove();
  //Change the id of an element
  cloneElement.attr("id", "section_"+parseInt($('.sectionType').length+1));
  //If element has options
  if(cloneElement.find('option').length)
  {
    //Finally append it
    $('body').append("<br/><br/>").append(cloneElement);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="section" id="section_1" class="sectionType">
    <option value="">------</option>
    <option value="05">test1</option>
    <option value="06">test2</option>
    <option value="07">test3</option>
    <option value="08">test4</option>
    <option value="10">test5</option>
    <option value="11">test6</option>
    <option value="12">test7</option>
    <option value="13">test8</option>
    <option value="14">test9</option>
</select>
<button>Clone</button>
```

Comment: It's working Fine . But I am going use one more condition if suppose i should not  remove value of "06" in the select box means what can i do. All the conditions success but i need to include this particular condition also.

Comment: Great, What we can do is, the same way we can check for the value of the selected index, if it's 06 or not.

Comment: @PrakashG You can get the value of selected index like  `console.log(cloneElement.find('option').eq(indexToRemove).val());`

Comment: OK, sure. Let me check.

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this.

```
$("#yourId").val(" ")//if your value has white spec else use like below line
$("#YourId").val("")//What ever you want to be selected, place your value in .val()
```

Comment: At the same time How can i remove the selected value from next select box

Comment: Are you calling any Jquery function when you are creating clone?

Comment: There you can write that code to remove newly created select box selected value, Make this code you write after your clone is created, and use new id

Answer (score 0):

I hope this will help you, if you need anything please ask!

```js
$("button").on("click", function() {
  $("#section_1")
  .clone()
  .attr("id", "section_2")
  .on("change", function() {
  var sec2Val = $(this).val();
    var delOption = $("#section_1 > option[value=" + sec2Val + "]").detach();
    optionHolder.push(delOption);
})
  .insertAfter($("#section_1"));
  $(this).attr("disabled", "disabled");
});

var optionHolder = [];
$("#section_1").on("change", function() {
  var sec1Val = $(this).val();
  if ($("#section_2")) {
    var delOption = $("#section_2 > option[value=" + sec1Val + "]").detach();
    optionHolder.push(delOption);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="section" id="section_1" class="sectionType">
    <option value=" ">------</option>
    <option value="05">test1</option>
    <option value="06">test2</option>
    <option value="07">test3</option>
    <option value="08">test4</option>
    <option value="10">test5</option>
    <option value="11">test6</option>
    <option value="12">test7</option>
    <option value="13">test8</option>
    <option value="14">test9</option>
</select>
<button>Add more</button>
```